# using DKIM.NET to sign Emails

Tags: .net, smtp, digital-signature, dkim

I'm looking for a free .NET solution to sign my outgoing emails and i found this one available on github.com/dmcgiv/DKIM.Net. 
I can't find any DLL. So, should I add this as a project in my Solution and  then make a reference to it ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's one way to do it. Another would be to build it and then just reference the assembly.